# Undefined index: action with code-snippets to change register page

Tags: functions

I see this error

**Notice: Undefined index: action in /home/olexywro/public_html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(352) : eval()'d code on line 6**

in my login page with this code snippets:

```
// Redirect Registration Page
function my_registration_page_redirect()
{
    global $pagenow;

    if ( ( strtolower($pagenow) == 'wp-login.php') && ( strtolower( $_GET['action']) == 'register' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/zarejestruj-sie/'));
    }
}
add_filter( 'init', 'my_registration_page_redirect' );
```

Somone could me tell me why?

6th line of this code:

```
if ( ( strtolower($pagenow) == 'wp-login.php') && ( strtolower( $_GET['action']) == 'register' ) ) {
```

Comment: The culprit is likely that the `action` GET variable is not set. Changing `( strtolower( $_GET['action'])` to `isset($_GET['action']) && strtolower( $_GET['action'])` should solve the immediate issue. On a side note, it looks like you're using this "snippet ops" plugin to execute code you're storing as a string via PHP's `eval()` - this can be a very dangerous practice and open your site to a plethora of security vulnerabilities. I'd recommend looking into alternate solutions to whatever problem that plugin is solving, unless you understand and are comfortable with the risks it presents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
strtolower( $_GET['action'])
```

But you're not checking if `$_GET['action']` exists first. You can't count on it being set, because when you visit wp-login.php, it doesn't have `?action=` in the URL, but this hook still fires.

So you need to add `isset( $_GET['action'] )` to your conditions:

```
if ( 
    strtolower($pagenow) == 'wp-login.php' &&
    isset( $_GET['action'] ) &&
    strtolower( $_GET['action'] ) == 'register'
) {

}
```